Power Automate - Flow runs when an item is modified but it's ignoring the condition
I have a flow that is set to run when a list item is modified. My first step is a condition, which the flow completely ignores. It sends the email no matter what that column equals. Am I using the wrong type of workflow trigger or something?
Any help would be appreciated.

I have changed the condition to another column, deleted it, ensured it's false in the list item. The flow sends the email no matter what.

what is the SendEmail column type? you can click on the "When item is modified" action for one run and check how the value is been passed?

also how you are editing the item? using built-in SharePoint forms? or using Power Apps? most probably your item is been set to True either using a default value for the column, or using another flow

It's a choice column. The default value is no, so the user would have to change the value to equal yes, which is what should trigger the flow to run. I'm editing the item using the out-of-the-box SharePoint forms.

are you sure the value is saved as no inside sharepoint and the condition is not read the value correctly? can you show the column setting?

Just check once, if there is a default value set in your SharePoint column setting.

The default value is NO. The user will change it to YES, which should trigger the workflow.

Can you make sure to use the "SendEmail/Value" ??   This will be the YES or NO text.
@triggerOutputs()?['body/SendEmail/Value']
Otherwise, you will have the full internal data for "SendEmail".
"SendEmail":{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":0,"Value":"Yes"}

Even if it has full data I don't believe the condition would result in false, it should result in an error

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
